# ToolsStripDropDownButton doesn't respond to PerformClick

Tags: c#, winforms

I added a System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton in my Windows forms application and now I'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut for clicking this button

However, when I invoke button.PerformClick() it simply doesn't open:

```
void _Cnc_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs ){
    btnFiltros.PerformClick();
}
```

Is this by design? Is there another way to simulate the click or properly open the dropdown?

**Edit**

The reason I'm doing this is I have a working application that is going to be used in a mouseless device, so I have to make the whole navigation possible from the keyboard

Comment: It is bad code, PerformClick() just fires the Click event.  If you want to see the dropdown then you'll have to call ShowDropDown().  Pretty unlikely that a KeyPress event is correct place to make that happen btw, the intent is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Does your form have the `KeyPreview` property set ? You need it to receive all key events.

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to the control with focus.

Form http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx

For the toolstripdropdownbutton you have to select the drop down item first. The following code snippet shows how to do that.

```
// This method shows the drop-down for the first item 
// in the form's ToolStrip. 
private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripDropDownItem item = this.toolStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripDropDownItem;

    if (item.HasDropDownItems)
    {
        item.ShowDropDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have set a breakpoint on the btnFiltros.PerformClick(); and I see it's breaking there

Comment: Is the button enabled and visible ?

Comment: Yes, I can check this from the watch window when I break it at the breakpoint

Comment: I think you may need to make sure you are selecting the drop down item from the menu first.